# Craft 3 CMS Javascript files disappearing from the page when the page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, templates, craftcms

I'm using the {% js %} tag to load some extras javascript files to a template, but if I reload the page or move to another page and come back to the page, all the js files that I'm loading using the js tag disappears from the page. Please can someone tell me how to fix that issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Are your `{% js %}` tags in a part of your templates that's cached using the [{% cache %}](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/tags.html#cache) tag? In this case, the JavaScript is only added if the full template is executed, not if this part of your template is served from the cache.

This is a known bug ([see the Github issue](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/7758)) and will be fixed in Craft 3.7, which should be released in a couple of weeks.